# What's the reason behind "structure has extra field" error

Tags: haxe

Consider this code:

```
var t: {a: Int} = {a:100, b:200};
```

It does not compile with error: `{ b : Int, a : Int } has extra field b`

But this code compiles fine:

```
class Foo {
    public var a: Int = 100;
    public var b: Int = 200;
    public function new() {}
}
...
var t: {a: Int} = new Foo();
```

Why is the first case forbidden?

What can go wrong if there are some extra fields? And if something can go wrong why they are allowed in second case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has previously been discussed [in this issue](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3192), where Nicolas gives the following reasoning for the current behavior:

> The idea is that constant structures are not allowed to be reduced. This allows for instance to check for the following:
>
> ```
> function foo(o:{?x:Int,?y:Int}) {
> }
> var pt = { x: 0, yy : 1 }; // typo
> foo(pt); // goes unnoticed
> ```
>
> Also, it will gives error if you modify the signature of foo, for instance by removing a field.

However, the issue is still open and it looks like the behavior might be changed to allow this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/KQO4eFUb-N0

Nicolas explained:

> In your example both are considered constant values, and then an error
>   is printed because it has extra fields. That error was added in order
>   to enable code cleanup when you remove a field from a required
>   structure : it will tell you every place this field is still passed
>   (when passing a constant, which happen most of the time).
>
> I agree the error is a bit misleading when making simple tests such as
>   your own, but in actual code it rarely occur.

Comment: It is indeed quite strange
https://try.haxe.org/#Bf369
Have not noticed that before, so I agree "but in code it rarely occurs".